# Cakephp 2.3 baking with mongodb datasource

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I try to use "./cake bake" to configure my db (mongo) and  my models.
When I digit the command on my shell, my output is:

> Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.2 Console
>
> App : app
> Path: /var/www/cakephp/app/
>
> Interactive Bake Shell
>
> [D]atabase Configuration
> [M]odel
> [V]iew
> [C]ontroller
> [P]roject
> [F]ixture
> [T]est case
> [Q]uit
> What would you like to Bake? (D/M/V/C/P/F/T/Q)
>
> > D
>
> Database Configuration:
>
> Name:
> [default] >
> Datasource: (Mysql/Postgres/Sqlite/Sqlserver)

Where are mongoDB's drivers?

Answer (score 2):

Try taking a look at [this github repo](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb).

It will allow you to use MongoDB as a datastore for Cake